# Second partition to keep data safe?

Tags: macos, partition, ssd

I am new to Mac and I don't know very much about the operating system. I am used to Windows where I had a C partition for the OS and other partitions for data. When I wanted a fresh install I only formatted the C drive.

What is the best method to use this on Mac? I don't want to use an external HDD or a stick – I want to have them on my 256 GB SSD. I don't know what to do. I don't want to lose my photos and videos so please advice me.

Answer (score 3):

It is rare to need to reformat the operating system only part of your Mac.

### Recommended: Use one partition

I believe the overwhelming majority of Mac users have a single partition on their internal drive. This lone partition is used to store everything: operating system, applications, and documents.

The [UNIX-like file layout](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/30/mac-os-x-directory-structure-explained/) does a good job of keeping all these files organised and separate. With OS X 10.11, new security measures have further isolated the core system files from your own files.

### Back Up and Use Time Machine

In order to avoid loosing photos and documents, attach an external drive and turn on [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) for that drive. Time Machine is macOS's built-in back up mechanism. This will protect you from most problems.

In the worst case, you can wipe your Mac's drive, re-install macOS, and restore your documents with Time Machine.

### Upgrades and Recovery

Upgrades of macOS only update the operating system part itself, leaving both your data and user-installed applications untouched. The same applies for reinstallation of macOS which can be done from the [Recovery Partition](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) without touching your data.

### Optional: Isolating your documents

As a developer, I do separate my operating system and applications from my user documents. This is a habit from using earlier versions of macOS and before virtual machines made testing easier.

This approach is only a real benefit, if you use a separate physical device for the two partitions.

See Macworld's article [Keeping Mac OS and data on separate drives](http://www.macworld.com/article/1164891/mac-apps/keeping-mac-os-and-data-on-separate-drives.html) for how to set this up.

Answer (score -2):

Hy you can use disk utility, go to application -> utilities -> disk utility.

Héré you can find your machintosh disk select it and click on partition then you click on sign plus on bottom of new window, give it a name and size and create it.